# Very simple C# Windows Service - Malwarebytes quarantines it. Am I doing something questionable?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, antivirus

I am trying to learn about writing Windows Services, and I'm using C# to do it.  I found a tutorial on Microsoft's site here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It shows you how to build a simple Windows Service that logs some messages to the Event Log.  I more or less followed the instructions, and everything worked fine.  But it instructs you to use Designers and mysterious drag-and-drop components, and to rely upon a bunch of IDE-autogenerated code.  So, for the purposes of trying to actually understand what I was doing, I tried to make a (basically) equivalent Windows Service just from raw classes that I manually typed in, rather than from Designers and such.

It compiled fine, and installutil.exe successfully installed it as a service.  But when I try to start the service, I get the following error:

```
Windows could not start the Bob Manual Service Display Name service on Local Computer.

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Eventually I figured out that Malwarebytes (my antivirus program) is quarantining my project's compiled exe whenever I try to start the service.  It says it's infected with "Backdoor.Bot".  I have tried both debug and release builds, and it quarantines both.

Obviously I could just whitelist the exe or temporarily disable Malwarebytes or whatever, but I am completely new to this Windows Service stuff, and I am concerned that I am perhaps unknowingly doing something flagrantly wrong or dangerous in my code.

I am attaching my code, which is intended to be based on the Microsoft sample code but very simple - three small classes, a Main, a System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase, and a System.Configuration.Install.Installer.

Is there any reason why Malwarebytes *should* be quarantining this?

One thing that I imagine might look questionable is that I'm setting the account to ServiceAccount.LocalSystem, which that Microsoft tutorial says has "broad permissions" and so "might increase your risk of attacks from malicious software", but:

(1) That's what it is in Microsoft's sample code (and as I understand it, it's required for the EventLog stuff);

(2) I actually accidentally had it as LocalService at first, and the same error was happening.

```
namespace Project1
{
    using System.ServiceProcess;

    static class BobMain
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun = { new BobManualService() };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}

namespace Project1
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.ServiceProcess;

    public class BobManualService : ServiceBase
    {
        private EventLog eventLog;

        public BobManualService()
        {
            this.eventLog = new EventLog();

            if (!EventLog.SourceExists("BobSource"))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource("BobSource", "BobLog");
            }

            this.eventLog.WriteEntry("Super duper constructor!");
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}

namespace Project1
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Configuration.Install;
    using System.ServiceProcess;

    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class BobInstaller : Installer
    {
        private ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller;

        private ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller;

        public BobInstaller()
        {
            this.serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            this.serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

            this.serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            this.serviceProcessInstaller.Password = null;
            this.serviceProcessInstaller.Username = null;
            this.serviceProcessInstaller.AfterInstall +=
                this.serviceProcessInstaller_AfterInstall;

            this.serviceInstaller.Description = 
                "Bob Manual Service Description";
            this.serviceInstaller.DisplayName =
                "Bob Manual Service Display Name";
            this.serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "BobManualService";
            this.serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

            this.Installers.AddRange(new Installer[]
                                         {
                                             this.serviceProcessInstaller,
                                             this.serviceInstaller
                                         });
        }

        private void serviceProcessInstaller_AfterInstall(
            object sender,
            InstallEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try `ServiceAccount.User`?

Comment: Btw. `this.eventLog.WriteEntry("Super duper constructor!");` could not work if you've just created the EventSource. Look the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2awhba7a(v=vs.110).aspx). And one more thing:  You forget to set `this.eventLog.Source = "BobSource"`

Comment: Thanks Nitro.de - I have done the following, and the problem persists: (1) Changed to ServiceAccount.User; (2) Added in the mistakenly missing eventLog.Source and eventLog.Log; (3) Removed the log message from the contructor (although this had been working when I added it to the original Microsoft example, by the way); (4) Added log messages to OnStart and OnStop.

Comment: On what Platform you are? Windows 8+?

Comment: It's just the Malwarebytes heuristics doing their job, it just assumes this kind of thing is fishy (I can imagine installing services could be one method of malware execution). I wouldn't worry about your code.

Comment: @Kharenis my guess is the missing signing. I dont think that OP is signing anything of this code and that could break everything here especially if it's a service

Comment: @Nitro.de That could well be the case, let us know OP!

Comment: OS is Windows 10 Pro.  Is there a lower OS bound for this stuff? I mean, I assume I can't use 3.1... but is, say, XP supported?  

Nothing is signed, but (as far as I know) nothing was signed when I followed the Microsoft tutorial's Designer-based instructions either, and that worked fine.

Comment: With  `topshelf` http://topshelf-project.com/ you don't have to go through all this. The AV might be doing behavior monitoring, try changing your code to do nothing if it still detects it as a virus uninstall that stupid AV.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, in the `OnStart(string[] args)` method, there is no process being started that runs on a separate thread for a prolonged time. So your service starts and exists immediately. Please take a closer look at "To define what occurs when the service starts" in the tutorial that you've referenced. 
Basically just add the code that sets up the timer to the `OnStart(string[] args)` method and your service should stay alive.